# How can I program ST MCUs from USB disk without PC?

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, stm32, microprocessors, stm32f4discovery

I want to program (such as STM32F407 cortex M4 MCU) without PC, by using only MCU board, USB disk and USB cable. Binary(.HEX) file should be stored in USB disk. then bootloader which preloaded in MCU, should load binary file from usb to the program memory.

Is it possible to do it, as I describe above?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is entirely possible given a suitable boot loader.  I have implemented a boot loader on STM32 that accepts updates over serial, SD card or USB VCP; adding USB mass storage support would be a relatively simple extension.

Your boot loader will require USB mass storage device support, for which the USB controller must support operation as a USB host, and you will require a file system (could be read-only to reduce size). You will also need to support flash programming.